# date and graph alignment - Economic analysis

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics

I'm am running a fundamental economic analysis and when I get to visualising and charting I am not able to align the dates with the graph.

I wanted the most recent date entry to show on the right and the rest of the dates to show every two years.

I have tried literally everything and cant find the solution.

Here is my code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = pd.read_csv('https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/fredgraph.csvbgcolor=%23e1e9f0&chart_type=line&drp=0&fo=open%20sans&graph_bgcolor=%23ffffff&height=450&mode=fred&recession_bars=off&txtcolor=%23444444&ts=12&tts=12&width=1168&nt=0&thu=0&trc=0&show_legend=yes&show_axis_titles=yes&show_tooltip=yes&id=NAEXKP01EZQ657S&scale=left&cosd=1995-04-01&coed=2020-04-01&line_color=%234572a7&link_values=false&line_style=solid&mark_type=none&mw=3&lw=2&ost=-99999&oet=99999&mma=0&fml=a&fq=Quarterly&fam=avg&fgst=lin&fgsnd=2020-02-01&line_index=1&transformation=lin&vintage_date=2020-09-21&revision_date=2020-09-21&nd=1995-04-01')
df = df.set_index('DATE')
df['12MonthAvg'] = df.rolling(window=12).mean().dropna(how='all')
df['9MonthAvg'] = df['12MonthAvg'].rolling(window=12).mean().dropna(how='all')
df['Spread'] = df['12MonthAvg'] - df['9MonthAvg']

pyplot.style.use("seaborn")
pyplot.subplots(figsize=(10, 5), dpi=85)
df['Spread'].plot().set_title('EUROPE: GDP Q Growth Rate (12M/12M Avg Spread)', fontsize=16)
df['Spread'].plot().axhline(0, linestyle='-', color='r',alpha=1, linewidth=2, marker='')
df['Spread'].plot().spines['left'].set_position(('outward', 10))
df['Spread'].plot().spines['bottom'].set_position(('outward', 10))
df['Spread'].plot().spines['right'].set_visible(False)
df['Spread'].plot().spines['top'].set_visible(False)
df['Spread'].plot().yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
df['Spread'].plot().xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
df['Spread'].plot().text(0.50, 0.02, "Crossing red line downwards / Crossing red line Upwards", 
                     transform=pyplot.gca().transAxes, fontsize=14, ha='center', color='blue')
df['Spread'].plot().fmt_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')

print(df['Spread'].tail(3))
pyplot.autoscale()
pyplot.show()
```

And the output:

[image]

This is the raw data:

[image]

Comment: As we can not run your code, it would be nice if you could show us the output.

Comment: added...let me know your thoughts. Thank you

Comment: Can you show a piece of the x and y column of your data ?

Comment: I think it's time to read this before you get more and more questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: added the X and y data sample

Comment: I get a 403 (Forbidden) for that URL from Fred. Is there any chance it requires authentication?

Comment: I dont think so... I get it without any issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a couple of corrections to your code.

1. In your URL insert "?" after *fredgraph.csv*. It starts so called *query string*,
   where *bgcolor* is the first parameter.
2. Read your DataFrame with additional parameters:

   ```
   df = pd.read_csv('...', parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0])
   ```

   The aim is to:

   - read *Date* column as *datetime*,
   - set it as the index.
3. Create additional columns as:

   ```
   df['12MonthAvg'] = df.NAEXKP01EZQ657S.rolling(window=12).mean()
   df['9MonthAvg'] = df.NAEXKP01EZQ657S.rolling(window=9).mean()
   df['Spread'] = df['12MonthAvg'] - df['9MonthAvg']
   ```

   Corrections:

   - *9MonthAvg* (as I think) should be computed from the source column,
     not from *12MonthAvg*,
   - *dropna* here is not needed, as you create whole column anyway.
4. Now is the place to use *dropna()* on *Spread* column and save it in
   a dedicated variable:

   ```
   spread = df['Spread'].dropna()
   ```
5. Draw your figure the following way:

   ```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import matplotlib.dates as mdates

   plt.style.use("seaborn")
   fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5), dpi=85)
   plt.plot_date(spread.index, spread, fmt='-')
   ax.set_title('EUROPE: GDP Q Growth Rate (12M/12M Avg Spread)', fontsize=16)
   ax.axhline(0, linestyle='-', color='r',alpha=1, linewidth=2, marker='')
   ax.spines['left'].set_position(('outward', 10))
   ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('outward', 10))
   ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
   ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
   ax.text(0.50, 0.02, "Crossing red line downwards / Crossing red line Upwards", 
       transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=14, ha='center', color='blue')
   ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter(fmt='%Y-%m-%d'))
   plt.show()
   ```

   Corrections:

   - *plt.subplots* returns *fig* and *ax*, so I saved them (actually, only *ax*
     is needed).
   - When one axis contains dates, it is better to use *plot_date*.
   - I changed the way *DateFormatter* is set.

Using the above code I got the following picture:

[image]

Comment: in addition would you know how to extend the plot to also include the latest 12 values in the dataframe? Thank you

Comment: Probably you should take last 12 rows from your DataFrame (*df.tail(12)*) and use it instead of the whole *df*. If your DataFrame is not sorted by time, start from respective *sort_values*. Correction: Actually you should take last 12 rows from *spread*.

Comment: a question if I may. I have a plot that only shows like last 3 months of data however the length of data is much longer. How would you get the plot to show the length of data and not just the 3 month capture? My code is this so far 
plt.plot(np.arange(start, len(df)),df.values[start:])
plt.suptitle(df.name, fontsize=18)
plt.plot(current_idx, current_pat, c='r')
plt.text(current_idx[-1] + 0.5, price_c, round(price_c, 1), fontsize=15)
plt.plot([current_idx[-1]], [price_c])
plt.grid()
plt.show()